# Do any .NET libraries for couchdb provide authentication?

Tags: c#, .net, couchdb

I downloaded a couple of recommended libraries for working with couchdb but it seems that there is no functionality for authentication.

Do you know any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relax has connection authentication: https://github.com/arobson/Relax

Answer (score 1):

[LoveSeat](https://github.com/soitgoes/LoveSeat) supports [authentication](https://github.com/soitgoes/LoveSeat/blob/master/LoveSeat.IntegrationTest/CouchClientTest.cs#L31).